# Particle system wont work as emitter but will as hair

Tags: rendering, particles

I am trying to recreate the ['rendered in blender' tutorial on particles].(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv23dh6d3oE)     [image]
Rendering shows no particles yes I mean ctl-f12.
[image: screenshot]
I get a bunch of things on the plane shown in the video. I had to subdivide the plane to get more than a single emitter to show up but the video shows particles streaming after simply adding a simple emitter particle system.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what means *"[BLENDER file]"*? Did you forget to add the link? And which tutorial and video do you mean? (Links?)

Comment: I could not find attach my blend file which I had in previous post.

Comment: oh, I see. If you have uploaded your blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ you will get a link after the file is uploaded. Post this link here, otherwise, nobody can access the file.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Look at your emission settings. The *Frame Start* and *End* values are both set to *0.000*. This means all particles are emitted at frame 0. Try 1 and 150. Then all particles are emitted between frames 1 and 150.

Comment: THANK YOU. But.the upload site has not given me squat

Comment: Reducing the end frame to 85 didn't do anything and same switching emitter to vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Let it snow!

[image: particle settings]

Open your file, then

1. set the *Particle Type* back to `Emitter`
2. reduce the *Number* of particles to `1000`. One hundred thousand are too many.
3. scroll down to the *Render* section. The *Icosphere* is your snowflake. This is what you want to render, not a path. So set *Render As* to `Object`
4. ... and *Instance Object* to `Icoshpere`. Now you will see tiny snowflakes.
5. increase the *Scale* to `0.500` or whatever you like to see them better.

Switch to *Solid* mode <kbd>Z</kbd> and run the simulation. It should look as shown above.

Comment: Yes. It works during rendering animation but the viewport 'rendered display' shows nothing falling.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In the question you wrote Ctrl+F12 (=Render > Render Animation) does not show any particles. Does this work now? Don't the particles fall in the viewport as shown in my screenshot above? What do you mean by *"the viewport 'rendered display' shows nothing falling"*? Key Z > Rendered? Or menu View > Viewport Render Animation or when you just hit play? Ctrl+F12 and View > Viewport Render Animation should write the PNG files to C:\tmp and Ctrl+F11 should replay this rendered animation.